# scylla compile Problems encountered in the process

Tags: scylla

I'm compiling scylladb for execution/ configure.py "Could not find c-are: found unsuitable version" 1.10.0 ", but required isat least" 1.13 "(found / usr / lib64)/ libcares.so ）”, but I have already installed version 1.13 of c-ares

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
```

Could NOT find c-ares: Found unsuitable version "1.10.0", but required is
at least "1.13" (found /usr/lib64/libcares.so)

Comment: Hello, just do what it says, upgrade libcares.so to 1.13
(https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libc-ares-dev is on 1.15 in focal, so your OS must have it too, or it's time to update OS)

the other option is to use docker build (dbuild), see scylla docs on how to do it (README.md , docs/* )

Comment: My operating system is CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (AltArch)

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 7 lacks packages that Scylla needs to build. If you have Docker installed, you can run

```
./tools/toolchain/dbuild
```

this will drop you into an environment where you can ./configure.py and build scylla.

Comment: My system is  not installed docker

Comment: Then installl it.